# Selecting Related Rows in MYSQL but not limiting results based on WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables (though i'm not certain I really need to utilize the articlesDB table). I am currently stuck trying to figure out the SQL logic necessary. I can probably hack something together in PHP, but I get the feeling a proper SQL statement could skip that step.

Heres what I have;

### tagsDB

```
**theTag**-**articleID**
bear - 1
fish - 1
cow - 1
tiger - 2
cow - 2
panda - 2
```

### articlesDB

```
articleID
1
2
```

Rules:

1. Their are up to 5 tags per article.
2. Each tag *could* appear in each article
3. I know one of the tags ($KeyTag), but *not* the articles it
   appears in

I need an SQL statement that returns to me all of the tags that appear in any article that has the searched upon $KeyTag.

In the above example if I search for "cow", I'd get; bear, fish, cow, tiger, cow, panda. I am okay with duplicates (its sort of the point).

Additionally If I searched for the tag "panda", I would get; tiger, cow, panda.

Comment: Do you have the `SQL statement` you used to start with?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to choose all the tags that appear in the same article/s as a specific tag:

```
select theTag from tagsDB where articleID in 
 (select articleID from tagsDB
  where theTag  = '$KeyTag'
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT theTag FROM tagsBD WHERE articleID IN 
  (SELECT articleID FROM tagsDB WHERE theTag = 'cow');
```

SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dce294/1

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use `SELF JOIN` to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT t2.theTag
FROM tagsDB t1 INNER JOIN tagsDB t2 ON t1.theTag = '$KeyTag'
    AND t2.articleID = t1.articleID;
```

You should have index at least `INDEX(theTag, articleID)` on `tagsDB`.